# Passing Data into a Nebula.gl HTMLClusterOverlay In Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deck.gl

I'm am working on adding map clustering to an existing TS based React Application. The application uses Deck.gl. The [Nebula.gl HTMLClusterOverlay](https://nebula.gl/docs/api-reference/overlays/html-cluster-overlay) seems like an easy way to do this.

In the [HTMLClusterOverlay example](https://nebula.gl/docs/interactive-examples/world-heritage), They pass the data into the component like this:

```
<WorldHeritage data={data} />;
```

However, when attempting to do the same in my code I am met with this error.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<{ viewport?: Record<string, any> | undefined; zIndex?: number | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }>): ClusterLayer', gave the following error.
    Type '{ data: Feature[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ClusterLayer> & Readonly<{ viewport?: Record<string, any> | undefined; zIndex?: number | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ClusterLayer> & Readonly<{ viewport?: Record<string, any> | undefined; zIndex?: number | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: { viewport?: Record<string, any> | undefined; zIndex?: number | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ClusterLayer', gave the following error.
    Type '{ data: Feature[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ClusterLayer> & Readonly<{ viewport?: Record<string, any> | undefined; zIndex?: number | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ClusterLayer> & Readonly<{ viewport?: Record<string, any> | undefined; zIndex?: number | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<...>'.
```

The data I am trying to pass in is an array of geojson Objects (`Feature`).

Is there a way to add properties to a subclass like the one I am creating? If not, Is there a better way to pass the data in?

Here is the subclass I've created for reference.

```
class ClusterLayer extends HtmlClusterOverlay<Feature> {

    getAllObjects() {
        return this.props.data;
    }

    getObjectCoordinates(object: Feature) {
        const lat: number = object.geometry.coordinates[0];
        const long: number = object.geometry.coordinates[1];
        return [lat, long] as [number, number];
    }

    renderObject(coordinates: [number, number], object: Feature) {
        if (this.getZoom() > 5) {
            return (
                <HtmlOverlayItem
                    style={{
                        background: 'red',
                        padding: 4,
                        color: 'white',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        lineHeight: '10px',
                        maxWidth: 300
                    }}
                    key={object.properties.name}
                    coordinates={coordinates}
                >
                    {Object}
                </HtmlOverlayItem>
            );
        }

        return (
            <HtmlOverlayItem
                style={{ background: 'red', padding: 4 }}
                key={object.properties.name}
                coordinates={coordinates}
            >

            </HtmlOverlayItem>
        );
    }

    renderCluster(coordinates: [number, number], clusterId: React.Key | undefined, pointCount: any) {
        return (
            <HtmlOverlayItem
                style={{
                    background: 'blue',
                    padding: 4,
                    color: 'white',
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    borderRadius: 20,
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}
                key={clusterId}
                coordinates={coordinates}
            >
                {pointCount}
            </HtmlOverlayItem>
        );
    }
}
```